# Update label text periodically from within function

Tags: python, tkinter

the code below opens a tkinter window, with a label showing '0', and when the button is pressed, after 20 seconds, the label shows '9'.

Instead, I am trying to make the label update periodically, displaying the numbers 0 through 9 every 2 seconds, instead of just 0 and 9.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label, Button
import time

root = tk.Tk()
label = Label(root, text=0)
label.pack()

def loop():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(2)
        label.config(text=i)

Button(root, text='Press me!',command=loop).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: don't use `time.sleep` and don't use loops, use `after` to "loop", there are plenty of examples on this site and elsewhere on how to do this

Comment: Right.  It is IMPORTANT to remember that all GUI frameworks are event driven.  When you create or update a UI element, nothing gets drawn.  That just sends a message.  The message can't be handled until you get back to `root.mainloop`.  Until your handler returns, the UI is completely frozen.  Handlers need to run briefly and return.

Answer (score 0):

```
def loop():
    for i in range(10):
        root.after(2000, lambda:label.config(text=i))
```

EDIT:

The above would only upgrade once. As @Matiiss suggested, we could do:

```
    def loop():
        for i in range(10):
            root.after(2000*(i+1), lambda:label.config(text=i))
```

Comment: No, that updates the Label ten times, all of them two seconds in the future (so only one update will actually be visible).  And they'd all update the Label to show "10", since `i` will have reached its final value before any of the lambda actually get executed.

Comment: your example can be fixed by simply using `root.after(2000 * (i + 1), ...)` so that each call is scheduled after a longer period of time (2 seconds) than the previous one

Comment: You need to use argument with default value in `lambda`, otherwise all scheduled tasks will show same text '9'.